# How to show that this matrix inequality holds?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm looking for a proof (and if possible some reference material for further study) for the following matrix inequality:

$$ B^\top B \succcurlyeq (B^\top A)(A^\top A)^{-1}(A^\top B) $$

I found this in a script without any given conditions on the matrices, so is this true in general (for matrices of appropriate dimensions)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll assume that $A$ is $n\times m$ with $n\geq m$ and $r=$rank($A$)=$m$, so $A^TA$ is invertible. Let $A=UDV^T$ be the SVD (Spectral Value Decomposition) of $A$. Recall that $D$ is an $n\times m$ matrix with zeros except in the principal diagonal, where it has the singular values of $A$. Also, $U$ is $n\times n$ and $V$ is $m\times m$ and both are orthogonal.

It is easy to see that 
$$
A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T=UD(D^TD)^{-1}D^TU^{T}.
$$
Therefore, because this is a spectral decomposition of $A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$, you can see that the eigenvalues of $A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$ are $\leq 1$ (in fact $r$ are one and the rest zero). Therefore, 
$$
A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T\preceq I_n.
$$
If $B$ is $m\times n$, it is a known fact that 
$$
B^T[A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T]B\preceq B^TI_nB=B^TB.
$$
Tell me if you need more details.

**Proposition**: If $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ symmetric matrices such that $A\succeq B$, and $X$ is a $n\times m$ arbitrary matrix, then $X^TAX\succeq X^TBX$.

*Proof*: Since $A-B\succeq 0$, we can define $S=\sqrt{A-B}$, i.e, a symmetric matrix $S$ such that $S^2=A-B$. Therefore, 
$$
X^T(A-B)X=X^TS^2X=(SX)^T(SX).
$$
So for every $v\in\mathbb{R}^m$, 
$$
v^T(SX)^T(SX)v= (SXv)^T(SXv)\geq 0.
$$
Then, $X^T(A-B)X=X^TS^2X\succeq 0$.

Comment: 1. Sorry if this is obvious but for my own clarification: The eigenvalues of $A(A^\top A)^{-1}A^\top$ are given by the eigenvalues of $D(D^\top D)^{-1}D^\top$, which is square with $r$ ones on the principal diagonal and zeros everywhere else, right?

2. Why do you write "If $B$ is $m \times n$, it is a known fact that..."? Doesn't the inequality after that follow by simple multiplication?

Comment: 1) Yes, that is the case. Note that $D(D^TD)^{-1}D^T$ is $n\times n$, so the diagonal has $r\leq n$ ones and the rest zeros. To see it just perform the operation. 2) Yes, if $A\geq B$ then $X^TAX\geq X^TBX$. I'll add it to the answer.